# react tailwind horizontal scroll containing cards behaving weird

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

So, for some reason instead of being able to scroll horizontally inside the component when it is overflown, the cards shrink and fit the component. I don't understand why, any explanation is greatly appreciated. Code and images are here bellow, a great thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
<div className='  w-5/6 h-64 mx-auto mt-24 mb-20 '>
    <p className='h-12 text-xl font-medium ml-5 flex items-center drop-shadow-lg'>Animations</p>
    <div className='bg- w-full h-48 flex flex-row overflow-x-scroll scrollbar-hide'>
        <div className='bg-blue-300 h-full w-72 ml-4 rounded-md '></div>
        <div className='bg-blue-300 h-full w-72 ml-4 rounded-md '></div>
        <div className='bg-blue-300 h-full w-72 ml-4 rounded-md '></div>
        <div className='bg-blue-300 h-full w-72 ml-4 rounded-md '></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children of a flex layout implicitly have `flex-shrink: 1` by default, which will attempt to shrink the main axis dimension of the children to fit the container. If you would rather this shrinking not happen, override `flex-shrink: 1` by applying `flex-shrink: 0` via the `shrink-0` class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class='w-5/6 h-64 mx-auto mt-24 mb-20'>
    <p class='h-12 text-xl font-medium ml-5 flex items-center drop-shadow-lg'>Animations</p>
    <div class='bg- w-full h-48 flex flex-row overflow-x-scroll scrollbar-hide'>
        <div class='bg-blue-300 h-full w-72 ml-4 rounded-md shrink-0'></div>
        <div class='bg-blue-300 h-full w-72 ml-4 rounded-md shrink-0'></div>
        <div class='bg-blue-300 h-full w-72 ml-4 rounded-md shrink-0'></div>
        <div class='bg-blue-300 h-full w-72 ml-4 rounded-md shrink-0'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```